# F# idiomatic way of determining if all (key*value) list entries sharing key have same singular distinct value

Tags: dictionary, f#, idioms

Given a set of dictionaries of `int*string` where the first is the "primary", I want to answer the question:

> For all additional dictionaries, do they **all** have the same values for the same keys as the primary?

I've currently achieved this by doing the following:

```
let allSame = primary @ remaining
              |> Seq.groupBy (fun (pos, _) -> pos)
              |> Seq.map (fun (pos, items) -> (pos, items |> Seq.map (fun (_, name) -> name) |> Seq.distinct |> List.ofSeq))
              |> Seq.exists (fun (_, names) -> names.Length > 1))
```

I'm wondering if there's a more idiomatic way of achieving this?

Going through the duplication of `pos` in the grouping `int * (int * string) list` and then having to reduce down to `int * string list` seems a bit redundant, but `groupBy` unfortunately doesn't offer a value projection overload.

---

### EDIT

Given a bunch of items (fields) with simplified structure `{SortOrder:int;Name:string;...}`

I'm going: `Field list -> (int * string) list`

The "primary" is just the head of the list, it doesn't matter which one I pick as "primary" because I'm only interested in whether all fields with the same position also share the same name.

That's why I'm grouping by position, then reducing down to a distinct list of names, and just counting the entries (>1 obviously means some divergence).

---

### Eventual Solution

Here's what I ended up with:

```
let primary = getFields <| fst x
let allSame = (primary) @ ((tail |> List.map (fun (m,_) -> getFields m)) |> List.collect (fun e -> e))
                |> Seq.sortBy (fun (pos, _) -> pos)
                |> Seq.pairwise
                |> Seq.forall (fun ((_,namex),(_,namey)) -> Seq.forall2 (=) namex namey)
if allSame then
  Some (fst x)
else
  failwith "Some error message here"
```

Comment: in this case I would just use `System.Collection.Generic.Dictionary`s, check the key-count and test if the values for all keys match - yours seem somewhat strange - isn't it supposed to be `Seq.forall` instead - and even if what if one your input dictionaries hat multiple values per key (the other one is missing)?

Comment: aside from this - sorting both, then zipping then comparing the tuples for matching parts in both components seem reasonable as well (O(n log n))

Comment: I've simplified it somewhat, the `Seq.exists` comes later in the actual code, I test for different key counts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Carsten said in his comment, sort by key and then compare each KeyValuePair. As an added benefit, [`Seq.forall`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370522.aspx) is lazy and stops evaluation at the first mismatch.

```
[primary; remaining1; remaining2]
|> Seq.map (Seq.sortBy (fun (KeyValue(k,_)) -> k))
|> Seq.pairwise
|> Seq.forall (fun (x, y) -> Seq.forall2 (=) x y)
```

Comment: +1 and accepted, this led me to the solution for the problem, needed some tweaking as I'm not using keyvalues, but tuples, but got there in the end with some tuple comprehensions.

Answer (score 0):

Going for pure readability, I'd prefer to define a helper function to test each key/value pair.

Your question doesn't say if a mismatched key should be OK or not, so pick whichever is appropriate:

(mismatched key is OK)

```
let looselyAllSame (primary :: remaining) = 
     let hasDifferentName key value = 
          primary |> Map.tryFind key |> Option.exists ((<>) value) 
     not (remaining |> List.exists (Map.exists hasDifferentName))
```

(mismatched key is not OK)

```
let strictlyAllSame (primary :: remaining)= 
     let hasSameName key value = 
          primary |> Map.tryFind key |> Option.exists ((=) value) 
     remaining |> List.forall (Map.forall hasSameName)
```